# How to get acess to .NET Core 3.1 COM object from another app?

Tags: c#, .net-core, com

I made a sample .NET Core 3.1 COM object using this manual https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyKeyFileAttribute("xxx.snk")]
namespace authcore
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("8C097D17-69ED-417E-A357-0299D07F6B2B")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IServer
    {
        public int GetValue();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("7C046A5F-0AC9-4F82-B8AB-B6F1E2FA8DF9")]
    public class Server : IServer
    {
        public int GetValue()
        {
            return 335;
        }
    }
}
```

I've built&registered COM-object DLL. Then I wanted to access the GetValue method from application. I tried using powershell commands:

```
PS D:\> $obj = new-object -comObject ‘authcore.Server’
PS D:\> $obj | get-member


   TypeName: System.__ComObject

Name                      MemberType Definition
----                      ---------- ----------
CreateObjRef              Method     System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(type requestedType)
Equals                    Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode               Method     int GetHashCode()
GetLifetimeService        Method     System.Object GetLifetimeService()
GetType                   Method     type GetType()
InitializeLifetimeService Method     System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()
ToString                  Method     string ToString()


PS D:\> $obj.GetValue()
Method not supported.
+ $obj.GetValue()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException
```

Please, tell me what I missed?

Comment: Powershell is not exactly the ideal tool to test this.  It doesn't know anything about the type of the object so can't know that GetValue() exists.  Supporting late binding requires ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual